# Choosing the right parameters to train a Tf-Idf vectoriser

Tags: text-mining, feature-extraction, text

I'm very new to the DS world, so please bear with my ignorance.

I'm trying to analyse user comments in Spanish. I have a somewhat small dataset (in the 100k's -- is that small?), and when I run the algorithm in a, let's say, naïve way (scikit-learn's default options +remove accents and no vocabulary / stop words) I get very high values for very common and low value words (such as spanish equivalents of "to", "at", etc.).

What would be the most effective way to train the vectoriser on a 100k long corpus of ~200 char long docs?

I was thinking of using a larger corpus of Spanish text or looking for a stop word removing implementation for Spanish, but would love to have some expert advise before jumping into it.

Thanks!

Comment: have a look at this answer for a general answer- http://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/12736/21024

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no silver bullets. But here are some suggests:

1. Use a better stopwords vocabulary. If you still have words like "to" and "at", then you are either not removing stopwords or using a lousy vocabulary. Try using the Spanish stopwords from `nltk`:

   ```
   from nltk.corpus import stopwords
   stopwords.words('spanish')
   ```
2. Use `max_df < 1`. This will truncate words that appear in more than that percentage number of documents.
3. The TF-IDF part that punishes common words (transversal to all documents) is the IDF part of TF-IDF, which means inverse document transform. Several functions may be used as your [IDF function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf#Inverse_document_frequency_2). Usually, IDF=$\log\frac{\text{#documents}}{\text{#documents where word appears}}$ is used. You could try a more punitive IDF function. sklearn does not seem to allow to specify it, but you can use `nltk` or `gensim` or easily implement your own TF-IDF vectorization. It needs no more than five lines of code.

I would try each of these suggestions in this order, and stop when it is good enough. It sounds like using a better stopwords vocabulary will be good enough for you.

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention, but of course you can add more uninteresting words to the stopwords list, if you have the need to do so.

You may also want to first evaluate the impact TF-IDF is having in your counts. I think this will work:

```
m = TfidfVectorizer().fit(docs)
c = [m.transform([word]) for word in m.vocabulary_]
for i in np.argsort(c)[::-1][:20]:
    print(m.vocabulary_[i], c[i])
```

You may have to adjust the code. Try to use with IDF disabled and enabled, and other tweaks.