# News Classification

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, nlp

Currently, I have a bunch of extracted news articles. I would like to determine whether a particular news article is related to a particular company. For example, "Apple stock dropped by 15%" should be related to Apple company. Besides that, "Tim cook involves in sexual harassment case" should be also related to Apple company. Can recommend me some strategies to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at 20ng dataset and it's classification techniques. It is a collection of news articles which are divided into 20 classes. It is not exactly same as yours, but similar. The second line you mentioned about Tim Cook might be a difficult sentence for classification, so I'd suggest you to have a good training dataset before you start.

For simple beginning, you can try text cleaning and tokenizations. Refer to [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12695/machine-learning-identification-and-classification-based-on-string-contents-ge/12736#12736), one previous answer already provided which has relevant links and further information.

For classification techniques further on themes, I found that [this](http://anthology.aclweb.org/N/N16/N16-1061.pdf) one gives a really good performance on 20ng

Answer (score 0):

I provide you some steps to perform this task:

1. extract plain content from the news, for example using [dragnet](https://github.com/seomoz/dragnet).
2. tokenize each text and represent them with vectors with the bag of words technique. A simple way to perform this is using [TfidfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) from sklearn.
3. Clusterize them using some classification technique like [k-NN](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html)(k nearest neighbors). You will find the k-NN sklearn implementation very helpfull.

The key to perform the task is using the **TfidfVectorizer** which weigths more the tokens that only appear in a few notices, like "Apple" and "Tim Cook". Using a simple count vectorizer will not be usefull.